# How can i determine for each table what highest number is

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML and i need to add a class to each of the parent td for the div that has highest numerical value in it. So i need to find each table , then within each table find which td div has highest value and add a class.

I tried this , but isn't doesnt do each table , only both tables combined

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, $('div').map(function(i,elem){ 
    return Number($(elem).text()); 
}));
 alert(max)
```

Here is html

```
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td></td>
<td><div class="ogffpts_0002">101.7</div></td>
</tr><tr>
<td></td>
<td><div class="ogffpts_0006">101.6</div></td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>

<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td></td>
<td><div class="ogffpts_0004">88.7</div></td>
</tr><tr>
<td></td>
<td><div class="ogffpts_0007">101.9</div></td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

I want the result to be this

```
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td></td>
<td class="highest"><div class="ogffpts_0002">101.7</div></td>
</tr><tr>
<td></td>
<td><div class="ogffpts_0006">101.6</div></td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>

<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td></td>
<td><div class="ogffpts_0004">88.7</div></td>
</tr><tr>
<td></td>
<td class="highest"><div class="ogffpts_0007">101.9</div></td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What causes you the problem? Finding a table? Reading values of cells? Finding maximum? Or adding a class? Please edit your post and show what you have done so far.

Comment: `$('div').map` finds all the divs across all the tables. You need to loop each of your tables then find the divs within that table. Can you specify which part you're having trouble with?

Comment: My suggestion is using `.each()` to loop through the tables --> `$('table').each(function () {`  --  Within that you can use `$(this)` to map out your divs *within each table*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get all values of elements in array using `.map()` and find max of them. Then loop through elements and add target class to element that has same value.

```
$('table').each(function(){ 
  var maxVal = Math.max.apply(Math, $('div', this).map(function(){ 
    return +$(this).text(); 
  }).toArray());
  $('div', this).each(function(){ 
    $(this).text() == maxVal && $(this).addClass('highest');
  });
});
```

```js
$('table').each(function(){ 
  var maxVal = Math.max.apply(Math, $('div', this).map(function(){ 
    return +$(this).text(); 
  }).toArray());
  $('div', this).each(function(){ 
    $(this).text() == maxVal && $(this).addClass('highest');
  });
});
```

```css
.highest {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><div class="ogffpts_0002">101.7</div></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="ogffpts_0006">101.6</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><div class="ogffpts_0004">88.7</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><div class="ogffpts_0007">101.9</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```